# watch variables that change with the level of recursion?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm just debugging a recursive function, and the best on-the-fly inspection tool that I've got at the moment is the Immediate window.

Is there anything that can be done to auto update the watch window based on the most recent level of recursion?

The watch behaviour that I'm having is that the added watch variable is the one I added, and not the new instance of it.

Perhaps this would be good as a VS feature request.  i.e. show me these variables relative to where I am on the call stack.

Comment: I allways thought the watch-window will update ... just tried and yes the watch window will change and even shop the changing values in red rather then black ... maybe I don't understand your question?

Comment: You mean like the `locals` window? Pretty much shows the state of variables in your local scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Watch Window**, the **Autos Window** and the **Locals Window** will all show you the current version of local variables.

And you also have the hover and pin features.

I suppose you're doing something with a reference type and/or a static var, but given the level of detail in the question it's hard to say.

Comment: that hover and pin feature is neat.  Never pressed it before.  Thanks.   You are right, Watch is displaying the most recent item in the stack... so I'll award you the answer (my mistake).  Still... it would be nice to be able to get some kind of customisable recursive depth information.  Is hand designing this the only way?

Comment: You can backtrack using the __Call Stack__ window, Autos and Locals will play along.

Answer (score 1):

I've not got visual studio at hand to find a better solution , but you could always add `Debug.WriteLine` to print a value to the output window